# which php version support following syntax

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3

I use following syntax on my local machine

```
$userRoles = $this->CI->Appusers->getUserRoles()['dbresults'];
```

function return array with a key 'dbresults'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called [array dereferencing](http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2012/03/php-array-dereferencing/) and was [introduced in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)